# Print next N lines containing ":" after matched word - using oneliner

Tags: unix, awk, sed, solaris

I'm trying to extract needed lines from output of symantec's "lltstat"

Previously, I was using this piece of code (HOST_VAR is replaced by needed host in loop, like serverA):

```
lltstat -nvv active | awk '/$HOST_VAR/{x=NR+2;next}(NR<=x){print}'
```

but now situation changed and the number of lines is variable (can be 0, but also 10..)

output looks like this:

```
LLT node information:
Node                 State    Link  Status  Address
* 0 serverA           OPEN
                              eth0   UP      AA:BB:DD:CC:00:11
                              eth1   UP      AA:BB:DD:CC:00:11
                              igbe3   UP      AA:BB:DD:CC:00:11
 1 Bserver           OPEN
                              igbe2   UP      AA:BB:DD:CC:00:11
                              ixgbe1   DOWN      AA:BB:DD:CC:00:11
                              eth3   UP      AA:BB:DD:CC:00:11
```

tools that I can use are only sed and awk (grep is only the simplest one without regexes etc)
I was thinking about taking the line with server name; next; and print all lines that have ":" as it should be only in those MAC addresses, but I'm not that good in awk :(
thank you for any helpful hints

Comment: That original example can't possibly have worked as written since `$HOST_VAR` would not get expanded in single quotes.

Comment: In fact, it's in another script that replaces that HOST_VAR so in ksh it's called with correct value, like /serverA/{x ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `OPEN` only appears on the server lines this should work.

```
lltstat -nvv active | awk -v HOST_VAR=$HOST_VAR '$0 ~ HOST_VAR{a=1; next} a&&/OPEN/{exit} a{print}'
```

Comment: hm, 2 things:
1. what about last server, when there is no OPEN after it ?
2. it throws me errors :( awk: syntax error near line 1; awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: @morvy If this is the last server then awk just exits and that's fine. What awk is this? Can you narrow down what it is complaining about? You could try wrapping the patterns in parentheses. `($0 ~ HOST_VAR)` and `($0 ~ "OPEN")` and seeing if that helps. You could also try using the `match` function instead of `~` but I don't know what it might be complaining about offhand.

Comment: ok, so /usr/xpg4/bin/awk does it's job, but only for serverA :( serverB doesn't return any data, serverC the same

Comment: output is always like the example, number of nodes and number of interfaces on them is variable. before calling the command I know only node name. so now I have 4 nodes (currently testing on cluster with 4 nodes) and so I have serverA, Bserver, srvrC, testD (names are different because they are generated randomly)

Comment: @morvy If the script works for one of the servers it should work for any of them assuming you give it the right server name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65305/discussion-between-morvy-and-etan-reisner).

Comment: ANy time you get the error message `awk: syntax error near line 1; awk: bailing out near line 1` it means you are running old, broken awk (/bin/awk on Solaris) which should never be used by anyone for anything. Use gawk or /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk instead.